# How to pass argument to $store.getters with onclick event?

Tags: vue.js, vuex

How to pass argument to $store.getters with onclick event? I can see the default value but not the new value. This is my code

```
const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    notes: [
      { id: 1, text: 'Hello World 1, Vuex!', deleted: false}, 
      { id: 2, text: 'Hello World 2, Vuex!', deleted: true},
      { id: 3, text: 'Hello World 3, Vuex!', deleted: false}
    ]
  },    
  getters: {
    getNoteById: (state) => (id) => {
      return state.notes.find(note => note.id === id);
    }
  }
});    

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      result: '' 
    }
  },
  store,
  computed: {
    note() {
      return this.$store.getters.getNoteById(3);
    }
  },
  methods: {
    showText(id) {
      this.result = this.$store.getters.getNoteById(id);
    }
  }
});
```

and html

```
<div id='app'>
  <p>Default value: {{ note.text }}</p>  
    <button @click="showText('1')">1</button>  
    <button @click="showText('2')">2</button>  
    <button @click="showText('3')">3</button>    
  <p>New value: {{ result.text }}</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your getter is working perfectly. And it correctly returns `undefined` when searching for any item with an `id` of `'1'`, `'2'` or `'3'`.

Because the store doesn't contain any such item.

All your store items have number `id`s, none of them has a string `id`. See it working (I changed the template to send numbers):

```js
Vue.config.productionTip = false;
Vue.config.devtools = false;
const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    notes: [
      { id: 1, text: 'Hello World 1, Vuex!', deleted: false}, 
      { id: 2, text: 'Hello World 2, Vuex!', deleted: true},
      { id: 3, text: 'Hello World 3, Vuex!', deleted: false}
    ]
  },    
  getters: {
    getNoteById: (state) => (id) => {
      return state.notes.find(note => note.id === id);
    }
  }
});    

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      result: '' 
    }
  },
  store,
  computed: {
    note() {
      return this.$store.getters.getNoteById(3);
    }
  },
  methods: {
    showText(id) {
      this.result = this.$store.getters.getNoteById(id);
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.14/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuex"></script>

<div id='app'>
  <p>Default value: {{ note.text }}</p>  
    <button @click="showText(1)">1</button>  
    <button @click="showText(2)">2</button>  
    <button @click="showText(3)">3</button>    
  <p>New value: {{ result.text }}</p>
</div>
```

---

If, for any reason, you don't have control over the incoming type (you might have this problem when reading the value of an `<input>`, which is always a `string`, even when the type of the input is `"number"`), you might want to cast the value as number: `+'5'` => `5`.
So, as an alternative to fixing the template, as above, you could do this in the method:

```
 showText(id) {
   this.result = this.$store.getters.getNoteById(+id);
 }
```